# Receiving data in Ajax for a Div

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, message

So this one problem has taken me on a wild goose chase for a week or so now and I am really hoping that the problem will finally be able to be solved tonight. I'm not at all experienced with Ajax or JS so I really struggle here and am still learning. Here is what I hope to achieve...

I have a basic PHP messaging system in `messages.php` showing all messages between two users within a `DIV` which automatically adds a scroll bar when you receive more messages. Here is my DIV which does this:

```
<div class="list-group-message" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:385px;width:680px">   

 <div id="content">  

/// PHP MESSAGE SCRIPT

</div>
</div>
```

When you send a reply, it uses this Ajax script to send that data to be processed on `system/reply_system.php` if it notices you are talking to an automated account, it will also send the data to `system/sars_system.php` to be processed, this works fine for adding, and sending back messages...

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $("#content").load(location.href+" #content","");
}, 5000);
</script>

<script> 
function loadDoc() {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'system/reply_system.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $('#reply').serialize(),
  success: function(data) {

    console.log("success");
    var $content = $(".list-group-message");

    $content.text(data); // Here you have to insert the received data.
    $content[0].scrollTop = $content[0].scrollHeight;

    // Second ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: 'system/sars_system.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#reply').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $content.text(data); // Here you have to insert the received data.
        $content[0].scrollTop = $content[0].scrollHeight;
      },
      error: function(e) {
         //called when there is an error
         console.log('fail');
      }
    });

  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    console.log('fail');
  }
});
}
</script>
```

The nice gent who helped me with this script has informed me that I need to receive data back from `system/sars_system.php` and `system/reply_system.php` which basically look like this:

```
<?
require 'db.php';

    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $conversation_id = $_POST['conversation_id'];
    $sarssystem = $_POST['sarssystem'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

$usr_message = str_replace("'","\\'",$message);

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$usr_message','$user_id', NOW(), NOW(), '$conversation_id')");

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_conversations SET time = NOW() WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");
echo json_encode('success');
?>
```

But I am having a real big problem trying to figure out how to do that or what data I even need to send back or how I go about coding that in to the current script? If this all works, the final aim is to automatically initiate sending the scroll bar to the very bottom of the page every time this Ajax script runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax looks right because it is ready to receive data. In the php you can set the data to whatever you need, it could be the results of the database call. Here's a small example of sending some data back to the ajax script.

```
$data = array(
     'status' => 'ok',
     'message' => 'Customer account saved',
);

return json_encode($data);
```

If you know how to get whatever data you need on the server you can encode it and return it to the client.

The success method will run on the ajax object. It is passed the data and you can reference and manipulate/use it. Your code looks like it is already prepared for this:

```
success: function(data) { // <-- this is the data in json format from the server

    console.log("success");
    var $content = $(".list-group-message");

    $content.text(data); // Here you have to insert the received data.
```

Comment: So it doesn't have to be any specific data that I return? He mentioned I would have to edit the `system/` pages to return the data?

Comment: The content div should show all messages. The sars system is automatically generating a reply on the server to send to the user. 

The first ajax seems to be filling in all of the content except the reply. If this is all correct so far, then the data response for the second ajax call should be the reply message from the sars system, and it should be appended to the content as an additional message. The end result is the user sees all the previous messages, plus their post, plus the system automated reply.